# Function that returns a list of car models

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am writing a function that returns a list of car models. The input is a string of comma separated cars. Duplicate entries are not added to the result. The elements in the list should be in the same order as they appear in the input string. If the input string is empty, the result is an empty list. I modified it to support multiple model names, e.g. `print(car_models("Tesla Model S,Skoda Super Lux Sport))` gives `['Model S', 'Super Lux Sport']`.

```
def car_models(all_cars: str) -> list:
    if not all_cars:
        return []
    all_models = []
    cars = all_cars.split(",")
    for car in cars:
        unique_car = car.split(" ")
        if unique_car[1] not in all_models:
            all_models.append(" ".join(unique_car[1:]))
    return all_models
```

While testing the code, an error occurred:
[image]

And I can't figure out what's wrong, can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: There is no assertion in the code you've shown

Comment: @Vlad he mentions testing the code, i think the assertion is raised when running a testsuite, where the assertion is made

Comment: why are you "re-splitting" `car` by an empty space after splitting by comma?  Are the car names not just names separated by commas?

Comment: first of all, your list doesnt represent the Carmaker at all anymore, only the models so if you had a Tesla Model S and a citroen model S youd get [Model S, Model S], do you really want that? Also you mention you changed the function, did you also change the tests to reflect the new expected outcome?

Comment: @AirSquid I think he is "extracting" the model of the car, which apparently is just anything after the first space.

Comment: @AirSquid as far as I understand, after "resplitting" I get a list with elements, i.e. instead of ['Tesla Model S',] I have ['Tesla', 'Model', 'S'], which is convenient.

Comment: @seven_seas actually I will only get "Model S", regardless of the make of the car. The tester is not mine, i just send my work to gitlab using pycharm. This is some kind of system in the moodle at universities. Sorry, I'm not educated in this area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're appending `" ".join(unique_car[1:])` to the list, you need to use the same thing when checking if already exists.

Solve this easily by assigning that to a variable, so you can use the same thing in the `in` test and `append()` call.

```
def car_models(all_cars: str) -> list:
    if not all_cars:
        return []
    all_models = []
    cars = all_cars.split(",")
    for car in cars:
        car_words = car.split(" ")
        model = " ".join(car_words[1:])
        if model not in all_models:
            all_models.append(model)
    return all_models
```

Answer (score 1):

Checking for the existence of some object in a list will not perform optimally when the list is very large. Better to use a set.

Here are two versions. One without a set and the other with:

```
def car_models(all_cars):
    result = []
    for car in all_cars.split(','):
        if (full_model := ' '.join(car.split()[1:])) not in result:
            result.append(full_model)
    return result

def car_models(all_cars):
    result = []
    resultset = set()
    for car in all_cars.split(','):
        if (full_model := ' '.join(car.split()[1:])) not in resultset:
            result.append(full_model)
            resultset.add(full_model)
    return result
```

**Note:**

If order didn't matter (it does in this case) one could just use a set

Answer (score 0):

First, I suppose you misspelled the command and should be like:

> print(car_models("Tesla Model S","Skoda Super Lux Sport"))

And then, instead of:

```
unique_car = car.split(" ")
```

I should use something like:

```
unique_car = car[car.find(" ")+1:]
```

to have full name of the model compared. Even with:`unique_brand = car[:car.find(" ")]` you can be able to create a beautiful dictionary like: `{'brand1':[model1, model2], 'brand2':...}`

Besides, if the problem is coming from the test, please share your test code.